How to use File Streams and Storage Access Framework (SAF) to persistently access a single file without repeatedly asking for permissions
The idea is this:

User clicks on a select file button to select a file using the system file picker
Using file streams, the application saves the URI location to its internal storage
The application reads the file and does something with its contents
Next time the user opens the application, the URI location is read from its internal storage, and the file contents are read without any action necessary from the user

The idea is to prevent any permission requests since SAF does not need permissions for accessing a single file. The temporary permissions are also persisted so next time the user opens the app, they don't need to do anything, allowing for a seamless experience.
However, I'm having some trouble persisting this permission. I'm thinking it has something to do with the way the URI is stored (it must be converted to a string before it can be written as a byte array), so maybe the permissions information is lost?
Right now, the user is able to select a file, but when the app is restarted and they try to load the file again, the app crashes due to java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{...} requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
My code right now looks like this:
[package and imports...]


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                FileSelect()   // dialog for selecting a file
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun FileSelect() {
    // State variables
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var selectedFileUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }
    var fileContent by remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }

    // Open file from URI, set fileContent, and write URI to internal storage
    val openFile = { uri: Uri? ->
        selectedFileUri = uri
        uri?.let {
            fileContent = readTextFromUri(context, it)
            try {
                takePersistableUriPermission(context, it)
            } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        // Try writing to internal storage for future use
        try {
            val fos: FileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("URILocation.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            fos.write(selectedFileUri.toString().toByteArray()); fos.flush(); fos.close()
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Write URILocation.txt - success")
            
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Error writing to URILocation.txt
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Write URILocation.txt - failure")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    // Launch file selector
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        onResult = { uri: Uri? -> openFile(uri) }
    )

    // Handle select file
    fun buttonOnClick(){
        try {
            // Try reading URILocation.txt
            val fin: FileInputStream = context.openFileInput("URILocation.txt")
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Read URILocation.txt - success")
            var a: Int; val temp = StringBuilder(); while (fin.read().also { a = it } != -1) { temp.append(a.toChar()) }
            val uriS = temp.toString()  // URI String
            fin.close()
            // URI URI Object
            val uri: Uri = Uri.parse(uriS)
            // Read file at URI
            openFile(uri)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // If no URILocation.txt, launch file picker
            launcher.launch("*/*")
        }
    }

    Surface {
        Column {
            // Select file button
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(100.dp))
            Button(onClick = {
                buttonOnClick()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Select or Load File")
            }

            // Display file contents
            selectedFileUri?.let { uri ->
                Text(text = "Selected file: $uri")
                fileContent?.let { content ->
                    Text(text = content)
                    [Do something with the content...]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Takes file URI -> returns nullable string of content
fun readTextFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    return context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { inputStream ->
        BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use { reader ->
            reader.readText()
        }
    }
}

// Grant persistable permissions to URI
fun takePersistableUriPermission(context: Context, uri: Uri) {
    val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION

    // Check if the URI can be granted persistable permissions
    val takeFlagsSupported = DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)
    if (takeFlagsSupported) {
        try {
            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the URI does not support persistable permissions
        Log.d("MainActivity","Persistable permissions not supported for this URI: $uri")
    }
}


Is it even possible to do it this way or am I missing something? Thanks!

Switch ActivityResultContracts.GetContent() to ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument(). GetContent is not part of SAF; you cannot get persistable Uri permissions using GetContent.

This worked, I also had to replace "*/*" with arrayOf("*/*")
